# Cannot create main window?

Tags: c++, mfc

I tried to make a simple MFC GUI application with C++, but it seems to have problem at generating the main window(dialog?). When I'm trying to compile the code, following message shows :

> Unhandled exception at 0x00E7A9DC in GUI_Employee_0501.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEFEFF66.

and the break point stops inside **winmain.cpp**, at **pThread->m_pMainWnd->DestroyWindow();**. The value of **pThread->m_pMainWnd** is **NULL**, which I suspect as the cause of the problem.

Can you specify what is the problem here? I have a sample code and that is very similar to mine but that works, so I truly have no idea what is happening!

```
#include <afxwin.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(linker, "/entry:WinMainCRTStartup /subsystem:console")

CEdit *pFNAME;
CEdit *pLNAME;
CEdit *pSALARY;
CEdit *pDDAY;
CEdit *pMMONTH;
CEdit *pYYEAR;

CComboBox *pGENDER;

CButton *pADD;
CButton *pDELETE;
CButton *pSAVE;
CButton *pLOAD;

class ENTRY_FORM : public CDialog
{
public:
    ENTRY_FORM(CWnd* pParent = NULL) : CDialog(ENTRY_FORM::IDD, pParent) { }
    enum { IDD = dialog_main };
protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX) { CDialog::DoDataExchange(pDX); }

    virtual BOOL OnInitDialog()
    {
        CDialog::OnInitDialog();
        SetUpInterfacePointers();
        return true;
    }

    void SetUpInterfacePointers(){ ... does its own thing ... }

public:
    afx_msg void add() { PRESS_ADD(); }

    void PRESS_ADD() { ... does its own thing ... }

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};

class Program : public CWinApp
{
public:
    Program(){ }

public:
    virtual BOOL InitInstance()
    {
        CWinApp::InitInstance();
        cout << "CWinAPP:initInstance" << endl;
        ENTRY_FORM dlg;
        m_pMainWnd = &dlg;                  
        cout << "mpMainWnd" << endl;
        INT_PTR nResponse = dlg.DoModal();  
        return FALSE;
    }
};

//
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(ENTRY_FORM, CDialog)
    ON_COMMAND(button_add, add)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
//

Program theApp;
```

Comment: It appears that you are struggling with C++ and try to learn MFC without knowing the Windows API either. This isn't going to end well. At the very least you need to be intimately familiar with C++ or the Windows API, ideally both, before trying to tackle MFC. If you ignore the advice, you'll waste time, only to wind up with what is often called [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Comment: @IInspectable I think you're right. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change in `InitInstance()`:

```
return FALSE;
```

to

```
return TRUE;
```

This is because [CWinApp::InitInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ae6yx0z0.aspx) should return FALSE only in case of failure, and TRUE if all initialization went OK. In case of failure, `AfxWinMain` will try to destroy window pointed by `m_pMainWnd`, which is not possible (it causes Undefined Behaviour) because you assign to `m_pMainWnd` a local object (which is destroyed once InitInstance ends).

[edit]

S.B Bae - to investigate it further and find a root cause, you will need to debug place where m_pMainWnd should be set to NULL once your dialog ends. This should be in `CWnd::OnNcDestroy()` in wincore.cpp. There is a line `pThread->m_pMainWnd = NULL;` which apparently is not being executed in your application.

Comment: No! This is the standard way MFC Dialog programs are created. Just create one with the wizard. m_pMainWnd is usually reset to nullptr, when the dialog is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but I saw the exact problem when creating an MFC Dialog application. I found I had accidentally changed the application dialog Style (in Properties) from 'Popup' to 'Child'.  Toggling this can consistently toggle this error.  'Overlapped' seems to work just as well as 'Popup'.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/styles-used-by-mfc?view=vs-2019#window-styles